# Is there a way to prevent a callout from disappearing while scrolling in MapboxGL for iOS?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

**What I need to do:**

Scrolling the map while a callout view is present should not dismiss the callout view. The callout view should also scroll around with the map.

**What I have**

- My callout view is a subclass of MGLAnnotationView
- It is presented in `- (nullable MGLAnnotationView *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation;`

**What I've tried and didn't work**

1. I can build the framework, but modifications either don't take or I'm missing something: I've commented out the contents of `- (void)deselectAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated` in MapViewController.mm.
2. I've tried overriding `setAlpha`, `setHidden`, and `removeFromSuperView` methods of my callout view. None of them get called.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a `bug` [fix](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/6676) in **Oct 2016**: . I have also tried lately on a sample project where I have subclassed an `MGLAnnotationView`. It seems to works properly now as long as you have subclassed those two properties:

```
var dismissesAutomatically = false
var isAnchoredToAnnotation = true
```